Map Object Greyed Out
I am trying to turn an image into an equirectangular image to overlay onto an HDRI in blender. What I need to be able to is to map the image onto a sphere using GIMP > filter > map > Map Object
However "Map Object" is greyed out and I can't figure out how to "ungrey" it. I have tried changing the RGB composite space, but that may not be the right thing.

Looking at the source code, the only requirement is that the target is an RGB "drawable", so:

Make sure the image is RGB (Image > Mode > RGB)
Make sure that the target drawable is a layer, by checking the status bar or the Layers/Channels lists, and in particular:

Not a layer mask: 
Not a channel:  (frequent mishap with a saved selection)




Brillliant! Genius! Awesome! Thankyou very much. The image was set to GREYSCALE so simply changing to RGB made it available. I cannot thankyou enough. I have been tearing my hair out all morning over this.

Great. Then consider accepting the answer (checkmark near the upvotes) to tell others that the question is answered.
